# Bootable USB doesn't show up when used normally in windows

Tags: usb, multi-boot, bootable-media

I have a bootable USB with Gentoo Linux on it. My PC regularly uses windows. When I try to plug in my bootable USB to Windows like a normal USB, it doesn't show up in the files. It makes the normal sound when plugged in and I can see it in the device manager but I can't access any of the files inside the USB stick. How would I access the files inside of my USB stick?

Comment: What file system on the USB stick? Windows only speaks (ex)FAT(32), NTFS and ReFS.

Comment: It's FAT32 according to windows disk management

Comment: is it assigned a drive letter?

Comment: Ah it's not assigned a drive letter. Is that what's causing the issue? If so how do I add a drive letter?

Comment: Right click the volume in the graphical part > change drive letter

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify the file system on the USB Stick is one that is supported by Windows (FAT, FAT32, exFAT, NTFS, ReFS).
2. If so, open Disk Management and verify the volume was assigned a drive letter. If not, select volume and assign a drive letter.

[image]

Comment: When I do this I get a popup from virtual disk manager that says "The System Cannot Find the File Specified"

Comment: I got it, thanks so much!